# How to arrange the text in 2 lines of Textview if it's value is received using databinding expression

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, data-binding, android-databinding

As you can see in the code below I want the value in textview that has been set using databinding expression should be arranged in 2 lines after 22 digits in first line. Please help me to figure out how it can be done.

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/cart_card_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

                android:text="@{cartProductDetails.title}"
                android:maxLength="22"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/cart_card_image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve this behavior, depending on your specific requirements. Here's one approach that you could try:

Create a custom class that extends TextView and overrides the onMeasure() method, in order to insert line breaks into the text after 22 characters.

```
class WrappingTextView extends TextView {
public WrappingTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public WrappingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public WrappingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr){
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    String text = getText().toString();
    int textLength = text.length();
    if (textLength > 22) {
        String newText = text.substring(0, 22) + "\n" + text.substring(22);
        setText(newText);
    }
}
}
```

Change the TextView tag in your layout file to use your custom class and add the attribute android:inputType="textMultiLine" and android:maxLines="2"

```
<com.example.WrappingTextView
android:id="@+id/cart_card_title"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:text="@{cartProductDetails.title}"
android:maxLength="22"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:maxLines="2"
android:textSize="13sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="@color/black"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/cart_card_image"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

This way it should wrap the text after 22 digits in the first line. Keep in mind that this code will only work if the textView width is not fixed and you expect the text to wrap. If textView width is fixed you need to handle that with Ellipsize or something similar.

Comment: Dont you think android:maxLength="22" will break your code?